# Ember.computed.apply() shared getter/setter

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Beginning with Ember 1.12, the below code block generates a [deprecation warning](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_computed-properties-with-a-shared-getter-and-setter) because of changes to encourage using distinct getters and setters.  I understand the concept, but I'm not sure how to refactor something that uses `Ember.computed.apply()` in such a way that these deprecation warning are resolved.

```
var args = this.constructor.primaryKeys.concat(function(_, setValue) {
  var keyNames = this.constructor.primaryKeys;
  if (setValue === undefined) {
    var key, value;
    for (var i = 0; i < keyNames.length; i++) {
      key   = keyNames[i];
      value = this.get(key);

      if (!Ember.isNone(value)) {
        return value;
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (this.get('primaryKey') !== setValue) {
      this.set(keyNames[0], setValue);
    }
    return setValue;
  }
});
var primaryKey = Ember.computed.apply(Ember, args);
```

[Twiddle demonstrating the problem](http://ember-twiddle.com/a120363b8f65ad57cbc0)

Comment: The deprecation warning isn't from `Ember.computed.apply` can you explain what it is you are doing here? the syntax you need to adapt for is
`foo: Ember.computed({ get() {}, set(key, val) {});`

Comment: That is the line that triggers the warning from what I can tell @Kitler.  I'm trying to refactor [this block of code](https://github.com/jclem/rest-model/blob/master/index-v2.js#L381-L409).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
    var keyNames = this.constructor.primaryKeys;
    var args = this.constructor.primaryKeys.concat({
      get: function() {
        var key, value;
        for (var i = 0; i < keyNames.length; i++) {
          key   = keyNames[i];
          value = this.get(key);

          if (!Ember.isNone(value)) {
            return value;
          }
        }
      },
      set: function(key, _, setValue) {
        if (this.get('primaryKey') !== setValue) {
          this.set(keyNames[0], setValue);
        }
        return setValue;
      }
    });
    var primaryKey = Ember.computed.apply(Ember, args);
    Ember.defineProperty(this, 'primaryKey', primaryKey);
```